# Edit multiple entries in a table in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a reference table with 4 columns and multiple rows, I want the ability to edit any of the rows in the table from a web page, and save it back to the database. Is there a control I can use to do this?

```
ID  Config_Type         Value   Value2
1   Archived_Months        24   NULL
2   User_Timeout_Mins      30   NULL
```

Comment: PLease, explain, do you want to change the schema of the table or just update the values in a particular column?

Comment: Have a look at LinqToSQL or Entity Framework.  Or if you want to go more lightweight, simply use an SqlCommand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a control for this and a series of steps you have to take to accomplish your task. The control is the DataGrid http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479339.aspx there are MANY tutorials if you Google for it. Here is one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET-2-0

Try 'Edit Rows in Gridview' in Google and you will get millions of results

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the name of the existing column of your table try this

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CHANGE [COLUMN] old_col_name new_col_name
```

if you want to change the value of the existing row of your table try this

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET col_name= 'new value' WHERE col_name= 'old value';
```